# parsing space separated text in C

Tags: c, command-line

I'm writing a program for a school project that is supposed to emulate the Unix shell, in a very basic form. It's basically parsing input, then doing a fork/exec. I need to be able to read arguments in the program (not as arguments passed to the program from the command line) individually. For example, I will prompt:

```
Please enter a command:
```

...and I need to be able to parse both...

```
ls
```

OR

```
ls -l
```

but the trouble is that there seems to be no easy way to do this. `scanf()` will pull each argument individually, but I see no way to place them into differing slots in a char* array. For example, if I do...

```
char * user_input[10];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    user_input[i] = (char *) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
}

for (int i=0; *(user_input[i]) != '@'; i++)
{
    scanf("%s", user_input[index]);
    index++;
}
```

...then `user_input[0]` will get `"ls"`, then the loop will start over, then `user_input[0]` will get `"-l"`.

`gets` and `fgets` just take the whole line. Obviously this problem can be logically solved by going through and plucking out each individual argument...but I'd like to avoid having to do that if there is an easy way that I'm missing. Is there?

Thanks!

Comment: Since this is marked as homework, would maybe using [strtok](http://midatl.radford.edu/docs/C/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html) be helpful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your use case is simple enough, you can do this with [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok):

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);
```

> The `strtok()` function parses a string into a sequence of tokens. On the first call to `strtok()` the string to be parsed should be specified in `str`. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, `str` should be `NULL`.

You can use `strtok` or `strtok_r` to split the string on spaces.

If you're doing something more complex, where some of the arguments could have (quoted) spaces in them, you're pretty much stuck parsing it yourself - though you could have a look at the source of a shell (e.g. bash) to see how it handles it.

kilanash helpfully reminds me of my obvious omission - [GNU getopt](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html). You'll still have to have parsed into separate arguments yourself first, though.

Comment: getopt is the fairly well-known GNU standard library for this. 

http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html

Comment: @Kilanash: Oh, duh. I've used it a dozen times, no idea why I didn't put it in my answer. Of course... getopt works on `argv` - the shell has already split the arguments up when they get to getopt. So it's more of a second step, after the initial splitting the OP's asking about.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like it will work...this is a very, very basic shell simulator, so I don't think I need to worry about quoted spaces. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Forget that `scanf` exists for it rarely does what you want. Get the whole line at once and then write code to split it up. `strtok` - the second most favored answer to this question - is also problem ridden.

Comment: For the typical, simple use cases that homework problems present, strtok is usually more than sufficient.  You get a +1 anyway for saying "avoid scanf" because I don't think I've ever seen scanf get used well.

Comment: Sufficient, sure. Teaches bad habits? Probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtok_r](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtok.html) to break the string up on whitespace. Note that it is a destructive operation (modifies the input string).

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if anything of this will help you:

[ANSI C Command Line Option Parsing Library](http://michael.dipperstein.com/optlist/index.html)

[The Argtable Homepage](http://argtable.sourceforge.net/)

Regards,
Tiho